# Is all the data in Firebase available to everyone?

Tags: javascript, python, firebase

Since Google is deprecating Channels and asking to switch over Firebase, I was wondering how the data is accessible on the public side.

Since you can connect to Firebase using JavaScript in the front-end, I believe anyone getting the keys (again, available in the init setup) can read and write data to firebase, thus having an impact on how the app works?

Moreover, my issue relies on the fact that the data transmitted to the customer is private but as far as my understanding goes towards Firebase, it's just a big JSON object filtered by keys, so available for anyone, am I correct or am I missing something ?

(For information, I plan to use Firebase as a replacement of Channels/Websockets, so I would send data from the server (Python) that would update the front (Javascript), but would contain sensitive data).

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: First line from that link: *Firebase Realtime Database Rules determine who has read and write access to your database*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a default Firebase setup, anyone can read any data from your project but only Authenticated users (with Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc) can add or modify it.

To solve this issue you need to implement security rules for your Database and Storage bucket.

To setup your rules first you need to determine which nodes you wish to protect, let's use a basic example, a To-Do's app.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "todos": {
            "$user_id": {
                ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These rules mean the following:

There's a 'todos' node that will hold all the todo's from all users.

Inside the 'todos' node each user will have their own folder and this folder will be named the same as their user id (this id is generated when they register in your app using Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc).

You will notice the following Strings:

```
".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
```

This means that only the user with the auth.uid that is named as the node can read and write that specific node.

For example, my auth.uid is eq45weq54eqwe and yours is eq213er2w1

I will only be able to read and write in the node {root}/todos/eq45weq54eqwe

And if I try to load the node {root}/todos/eq213er2w1 (yours), I will be presented with an unauthorized error.